# Closed subscheme defined by kernel of diagonal homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $\Delta : X \to X \times_Y X$ denote the diagonal morphism. Take $U = \textrm{Spec } A$ and $V = \textrm{Spec } B$ be affine open subsets of $Y$ and $X$ respectively such that $f(V) \subseteq U$.

> $\Delta (X) \cap (V \times_U V)$ is a closed subscheme of $V \times_U V =\textrm{Spec } B \otimes_A B$ defined by the kernel of the diagonal homomorphism $B \otimes _A B \to B$

My attempt:

Let $\delta$ denote the diagonal homomorphism of rings. Then it is clearly surjective so $B \cong (B \otimes B) /\ker \delta$. Moreover, we have $B \to B \otimes B \to B$ factoring through $\delta$ so this gives a closed immersion of schemes $\textrm{Spec} ((B \otimes B) /\ker \delta) \to \textrm{Spec} (B \otimes B)$.

I now wish to identify the former with $\Delta (X) \cap (V \times_U V)$. $V \times V$ gives the prime ideals of $B \otimes B$ so it remains to see that the prime ideals containing the kernel of $\delta$ is precisely $\Delta (X)$. Here I am unsure how to proceed because $X$ is a general scheme, not necessarily affine. Even restricting to the affine subset $V$ and considering $\Delta (V)$, I can't quite see the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just abstract nonsense – nothing specific about schemes at all. We start with a commutative square of the form below,
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
V @>>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
U @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
where the horizontal arrows are monomorphisms. The claim is that the following is a pullback square:
$$\begin{CD}
V @>>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
V \times_U V @>>> X \times_Y X
\end{CD}$$
Since $U \to Y$ and $V \to X$ are monomorphisms, $V \times_U V \to X \times_Y X$ is a monomorphism as well. Now the claim is clear: given a morphism $T \to X \times_Y X$ that factors through both $X \to X \times_Y X$ and $V \times_U V \to X \times_Y X$, it must also factor through $V \to X \times_Y X$.

Comment: I see that it is a pullback square, but how does this relate to our initial claim?

Comment: An intersection is a pullback.

Comment: Oh of course. Thanks!